# geoserver: wfs columns are missing due to null values

Tags: mongodb, gis, geoserver, ogc

we are currently checking up on [geoserver over mongodb](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/introduction/extensions.html) on our dev-environment.
we are having some difficulties:
we have a collection, containing different document which answer to the same structure ("schema-like").
when querying a wfs service from geoserver - some of the columns are missing.
we discovered that if one of the "columns" on one of the documents contains null value - the whole column  does not appear on the query response.

is there some configuration we are missing on the geoserver to return null values on wfs response?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply working correctly, to discover the available columns you should check the DescribeFeatureType results

Comment: But what if some of the documents contain null at one of the attributes, and some contain value? The whole column would not appear... Is there a way solving that?

Comment: I cannot comment on the specifics of the Mongo store, it's not part of GeoServer nor the GeoServer community has any involvement with it, you should ask Boundless about it. But sure, the attributes in the GML should appear for the documents that have a non null value.